# Как сделать что бы результат функции автоматически копировался в буфер обмена JS?

Tags: javascript

Помогите сделать так что бы результат функции roshan автоматически копировался в буфер обмена после выполнения подсчета.
У меня есть кнопка в HTML которая выводит на экран prompt куда мы вводим число, после чего мой скрипт прибавляет к этому числу два числа и выводит на экран в виде DIV.
Подскажите как сделать что бы то что выводилось в DIV то есть результат функции roshan автоматически копировался в буфер обмена
(извиняюсь за тавтологию)

```js
var timermin = 0;
var timermax = 0;

function roshan(x) {
  x = Number(prompt('Введите минуту'))
  timermin = x + 8
  timermax = x + 11
  return String("Min: " + timermin) + " " + String("Max: " + timermax)
};

function resultToDiv() {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = roshan();
};
```

```html
  <div class="calc">
    <div id="result"></div>
    <input class="inputStyle" type="button" onclick="resultToDiv()" value="Нажми для подсчета времени">
  </div>
```

Comment: `navigator.clipboard.writeText(roshan())`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно немного переписать функцию

```js
function resultToDiv() {
  const result = roshan();
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
  navigator.clipboard.writeText(result); // Запись в буфер обмена
};
```

Comment: если не обновлять страницу, и нажать еще раз кнопку подсчета и ввести новые числа, в буфере обмена останется старое число, это не комфортно для использования

Comment: и по какой то причине, даже при обновлении не всегда копируется новое число

Comment: @kosmodraiv `.writeText()` возвращяет `Promise`. Проверяйте с помощью `.than()` и `.catch()` - когда копирование происходит успешно, а когда что-то идет не так и узнаете причину.

Comment: @kosmodraiv этот метод единственный и работает всегда. У меня в сайте встроена такая функция и она ни разу не отказала. Если что-то не работает, значит неправильно логику пишите.